# typing Protocol valid for Enumerator member

Tags: python, enums, python-typing

What is the right typing to accept an Enumerator Type which should match a Protocol  ?
I mean the Enumerator should have members defined inside a Protocol

Here is a simplified code exemple.

```py
from typing import Protocol 
from enum import Enum 

class MyProto(Protocol):
   item1: int 
   item2: int 

def check_item1( e: MyProto, value:int):
    return e.item1 == value  

class MyEnum(int, Enum):
   item1 = 0 
   item2 = 1 
   other_item_not_in_protocol = 2 

check_item1( MyEnum,  0 ) #<-- pyright complains about everything :
```

Pyright complains

```
# Argument of type "type[MyEnum]" cannot be assigned to parameter "e" of type "MyProto" #in function "check_item1"
#     "item1" is invariant because it is mutable
#     "item1" is an incompatible type
#     "item1" must be defined as a ClassVar to be compatible with protocol
#       "Literal[MyEnum.item1]" is incompatible with "int"
#     "item2" is invariant because it is mutable
#     "item2" is an incompatible type
#     "item2" must be defined as a ClassVar to be compatible with protocol
#       "Literal[MyEnum.item2]" is incompatible with "int" [reportArgumentType]
```

Mypy also complains:

```
# error: Argument 1 to "check_item1" has incompatible type "type[MyEnum]"; expected # "MyProto"  [arg-type]
# Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: Do you want `MyEnum` to match *that* `Protocol` (it won't, for various reasons, including the immutability of `MyEnum`'s *class* attributes), or do you want a `Protocol` that `MyEnum` *can* match?

Comment: `MyProto` defines a type whose *instances* have `int`-valued attributes. `MyEnum` is a type whose instances *are* `int` values.

Comment: @chepner But those `int` values are also accessible as `MyEnum`'s attributes.

Comment: The type of `MyEnum` is `EnumType`, and not all values of `EnumType` (i.e., other enumerated types) have instances named `item1` and `item2`. Despite the syntactic similarities, enumerated types are *not* similar to what a protocol describes.

Comment: Replace your enum with `class Foo: pass`, create an object `f = Foo(); f.item1 = 3, f.item2 = 4`, and `check_item(f, 0)` will fail for the same reason. Just because one instance of `Foo` matches the protocol doesn't mean *all*  instances of `Foo` do.

Answer (score 0):

You need three things to make this type check.

First, make `item1` and `item2` read-only using `@property`:

```py
class MyProto(Protocol):

    @property
    def item1(self) -> int:
        ...
    
    @property
    def item2(self) -> int:
        ...
```

To quote the spec:

> By default, protocol variables as defined above are considered readable and writable. To define a read-only protocol variable, one can use an (abstract) property.
>
> — [*Protocol members* | Protocols, Typing spec](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec/protocol.html#protocol-members)

Second, use `ClassVar` to explicitly note that `Enum` members are class-level, not instance-level variables (although at runtime this is already the case):

```py
class MyEnum(int, Enum):
    item1: ClassVar = 0
    item2: ClassVar = 1

    # Other members do not need ClassVar
    other_item_not_in_protocol = 2
```

This is where the third requirements come in: Pyright [passes this](https://pyright-play.net/?pythonVersion=3.12&strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoDCANgIYDOZAaiSADRQAK4MYAxmEVALABQokUAKYoArtCw48UAKKjovBT1akKUALJwmYFgAotLdkQCUALkVQLUAAIJwCQXji9LUACaDgmGIIgBGHWSCRMBGUAC0AHyYKDBmPC4uAHTJzpapFjZ2DvDpbh5ePgBMAUEh4VGosblJKTyKyuRk6nCyYjqV9K0QprlI3n4mhCpUNFAAvFAADL39hYPEjdQg41C%2BudoAFg4A%2Bn0%2B2yjauyjbttpsHCuF3HW37p6sW6wA1rv9-oKDGvpg9ABuJCIIk%2B0RgoUiUAARmAOHEXCBBDARCAUEJEns-OMJgCgYJFLxHoIXm8fP4NF16JNQlAAMRQYCoPE8IA), but mypy [doesn't](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=60bef9909a2241ac8512e44a044379f3).

I'm not sure which one is correct. While the spec did say that `ClassVar` is necessary to differentiate class-level and instance-level attributes, nowhere did it say that instance-level attributes defined inside a `Protocol` must be shared by all instances of a particular class for a single instance of that class to be considered compatible with the `Protocol` in question.

And I could be wrong. Here's all the pages I checked:

- [*Protocols* | Typing spec](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec/protocol.html)

  > To distinguish between protocol class variables and protocol instance variables, the special `ClassVar` annotation should be used as specified by PEP 526. By default, protocol variables as defined above are considered readable and writable. To define a read-only protocol variable, one can use an (abstract) property.
- [*Type annotations* | Typing spec](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec/annotations.html)
- [*Class and instance variable annotations* | PEP 526](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations) (emphasis mine)

  > In particular, the value-less notation `a: int` allows one to annotate instance variables that *should* be initialized in `__init__` or `__new__`.
- [*Class and Instance Variables* | Python tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)